# Assigning a method to click dynamically

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a set of buttons in a table, but each button is a function of the elements in the same row.

```
<button (click)="(element.method)" mat-raised-button color="warn">
    {{ element.buttonName }}
</button>
```

The idea is that `(click)="element.method"` should be equivalent to `(click)="doyourstuff()"` since `element.method` is a string with value `doyourstuff()`.

It does not work unless I explicitly set the value as `(click)="doyourstuff()"`.

Anyone could give some insights on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function onClick and pass the method name. rom .ts file call the function of that method name with `this[methodName]();`

Try like this:

.ts

```
element = {
   buttonName: "Save",
   method: "onSave"
};

onClick(methodName){
   this[methodName]();
}
```

.html

```
<button (click)="onClick(element.method)" mat-raised-button color="warn">
    {{ element.buttonName }}
</button>
```

Another way is to find the function in json like this:

```
  element1 = {
    buttonName: "Save",
    method: () => this.onSave()
  };
```

and call it directly like this:

```
<button (click)="element1.method()" mat-raised-button color="warn">
      {{ element1.buttonName }}
</button>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jz2fa2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Adding it in a minute with demo

Comment: :D There will be a Correct ( a right symbol below the votes in grey, if you click, this will turn green). This means that this answer has worked for the one who has posted the question.